# how to get values from XML to int

Tags: java, xml

I am new to Java and I have a question:

Is there any possibility to store/set integer values in XML? I would like to set

- X0 = 123
- Y0 = 123
- X1 = 123
- Y1 = 130

from  xml file below

```
<line>
    <point> 
        <X>123</X>
        <Y>123</Y> 
    </point> 
    <point> 
        <X>123</X> 
        <Y>130</Y>
    </point> 
</line>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest create a `Point` class with attributes `X/Y` and getter/setters for X/Y.

Use [SAX parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) to parse the XML (There are other techniques also like DOM/ Pull parser etc.,) and populate Point object and add it to List.

See this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Write a simple SAX Parser. Check this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [parsing the XML code](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152). And then using `Integer.parseInt` to force the value (if it comes out as a string) into an integer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have (or write) an XSD for your XML, you could just generate the Java code to read this XML into objects.

This is usually done with JAXB. If you google that, you will find tutorials.

Comment: You could also start from a Java model and add annotations to map it to the desired XML.